# Use database property from external property file in grails 3

Tags: grails-3.0, grails-3.3

I want to use external property file for database configuration in production environment. i have tried some of solution from blogs and stack overflow but its work only for development environment.

```
grailsVersion=3.3.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create properties file in `src/main/resources` (if resources dir does not exist, create it).

then remove configuration from `application.yml` (if won't then it will override).
in `Application.groovy` load the file with this :

```
def url = getClass().classLoader.getResource("myconfig.properties")
def confFile = new File(url.toURI())
Properties properties = new Properties()
confFile.withInputStream {
  properties.load(it)
}

environment.propertySources.addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("local.config.location", properties))
```